# How to temporarily stop iptables on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I use IPTABLES in /etc/network/interfaces

```
pre-up iptables-restore /etc/firewall.txt
```

I tried searching for some thing like `/etc/init.d/iptables` on Ubuntu but that does not seem to exist.So if I have to stop IPTABLE for temporarily for sysadmin work how can I do that?

Comment: Dupe: http://serverfault.com/questions/129086/how-to-start-stop-iptables-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`iptables` is not a service, but a facility inside the kernel. That is why you can't stop it.

If you ever need to stop iptables quickly, here's my suggestion:

1. Configure your iptables to completion.
2. Save the configuration first: `iptables-save > /etc/iptables.conf`
3. Flush the iptables, and configure it 'open':

- All policies set to ACCEPT
- Configure all necessary NATs for your sysadmin to work
- If you use Policy-Based Routing in the mangle table, also configure it as necessary

4. Save the 'open' ruleset: `iptables-save > /etc/open-iptables.conf`

Now, whenever you need to quickly 'disable' iptables, do:

> `cat /etc/open-iptables.conf | iptables-restore`.

After that, 're-enable' iptables using:

> `cat /etc/iptables.conf | iptables-restore`

( `iptables-restore < /etc/open-iptables.conf` might also work; but I've read somewhere else that *sometimes* it doesn't work )

---

**ADD:** Newer versions of `iptables-restore` can directly read from a file. So the above commands can be simplified to:

> ```
> iptables-restore /etc/open-iptables.conf
> iptables-restore /etc/iptables.conf
> ```

respectively.