# Iptables didnt restore the new rules after reboot

Tags: debian, virtual-machines

i have tried many similar question like below, in my case i used VM with Debian OS in virtual box:

1. [How to start/stop iptables on Ubuntu?](https://serverfault.com/questions/129086/how-to-start-stop-iptables-on-ubuntu)
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52376/why-do-iptables-rules-disappear-when-restarting-my-debian-system
3. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-list-and-delete-iptables-firewall-rules
4. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-iptables-on-ubuntu-14-04

I have tried to flush the iptables rules with these command.

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Follows with these command

```
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t mangle -F
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -X
```

When i reboot the VM, I still got the same rules. I tried to use `iptables-save`, and i always got this rules.

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Mar 28 03:44:14 2018
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [127:23299]
:INPUT ACCEPT [14:1996]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [32:1947]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [32:1947]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:POST_public - [0:0]
:POST_public_allow - [0:0]
:POST_public_deny - [0:0]
:POST_public_log - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PRE_public - [0:0]
:PRE_public_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_public_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_public_log - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_direct
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_ZONES
-A POSTROUTING_ZONES -g POST_public
-A POST_public -j POST_public_log
-A POST_public -j POST_public_deny
-A POST_public -j POST_public_allow
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -g PRE_public
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_log
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_deny
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_allow
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Mar 28 03:44:14 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Mar 28 03:44:14 2018
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [4925:1051078]
:INPUT ACCEPT [4925:1051078]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4791:1080206]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [4791:1080206]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PRE_public - [0:0]
:PRE_public_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_public_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_public_log - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -g PRE_public
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_log
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_deny
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_allow
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Mar 28 03:44:14 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Mar 28 03:44:14 2018
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [4826:1030935]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4814:1084121]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Mar 28 03:44:14 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Mar 28 03:44:14 2018
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [4949:1054264]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4815:1084545]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Mar 28 03:44:14 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Mar 28 03:44:14 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [2653:591941]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2649:609004]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Mar 28 03:44:14 2018
```

What i want is like the rules below. I have set my `rules.v4` to these command:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Tue Mar 27 02:48:59 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Mar 27 02:48:59 2018
```

But whenever i reboot the system, i always got the previous rules...

What could go wrong with my configuration ? Am i missed something

I have tried to unistall iptables-persistent and reinstall again, but i still got the same rules...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is in your `rules.v4` is what is going to be used when the system boots. You can save your running conf `iptables-save  > rules.v4` and then it will persist post reboot if you are running `iptables-persistent`

It is because `iptables-save` only prints your configuration to STDOUT, but you want to store your configuration in the `rules.v4` file.

Comment: okay i have did, the`iptables-save  > rules.v4` command so what's next ?

Comment: i couldnt run `iptables-persistent`

Comment: you enable the service `systemctl enable iptables-persistent` but I think it does that by default so there should be no more steps involved.

Comment: it says, no such file or directory...

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/iptables

Comment: okay looks like i have to set both my `iptables-save  > rules.v4` and my `ip6tables-save  > rules.v6`

Comment: First i deleted my `rules.v4` and `rules.v6` and make the new one f\based my opwn rules. and than i set the `iptables-save > rules.v4` and for the ip6 i set `ip6tables-save > rules.v6`, and than i reboot the system, and the rules seems works now, but before i do all of that, i flush and delete the rules to the default setting.

Answer (score 2):

To save the current rules to a file, use iptables-save. For example:

```
iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

To load the saved rules from that file, use iptables-restore. For example:

```
iptables-restore < /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

Answer (score 2):

What I do is usually to put a firewall script into my /root folder which includes all iptables commands. At the end I add

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables.conf
ip6tables-save > /etc/ip6tables.conf
```

Then save, chmod + x the script and run it.

Then in my /etc/network/interfaces I add

```
pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.conf
pre-up ip6tables-restore < /etc/ip6tables.conf
```

to the iface lo section.

This also allows me to copy firewall settings between servers since I usually use a policy drop and only open needed ports.

**Also, a big security concern:**

`sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT`

This command sets the POLICY to accept. This means every port on your machine is set to be open. Always use policy drop and only open needed ports.

Answer (score 1):

iptables does not save your configuration per default nor does it restore the rules after a reboot.

Consider using Shorewall which is a wrapper for iptables that makes the overall configuration and maintenance easier. Shorewall also has the functionality to save your rules and restore them after reboot.

**iptables save**

```
sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules
```

**iptables restore**

You want to restore the rules of iptables before you bring up your interface, else attackers will have a small window where your network is undefended.

You might also want to make a series of rules for when your interface is going down.

Example

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
  pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
  post-down iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.downrules
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

Comment: there is no such `iptables.rules` files...

Comment: When you issue the iptables save command as shown, it will create the /etc/iptables.rules file. You cannot restore what you have not saved.

Comment: This is pretty dangerous, because you bind your firewall settings to a physical interface "eth0". This means that the iptables aren't restored if you don't bring up eth0 and interface names can change (especially with the new naming convention). Also in multi nic-setups this is can be a problem. Better bind it to interface lo.

Comment: @Broco this is the example taking from the ubuntu help page. If you have a single FW interface it makes alot of sense to bind it to the interface you use, if you have multiple interfaces and you arent into iptables i would again advice shorewall which is a wrapper for iptables. And if you bind it to the loopback interface you again need to make sure that lo is brought up before ethX i am not exactly sure what order the OS does this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try the UFW (Uncomplicated Firewall)?! https://wiki.debian.org/Uncomplicated%20Firewall%20%28ufw%29

Its a frontend program for cmd that uses IPTables (also you have gufw if needed) making the live alot easy to use the iptables

Answer (score -1):

You have to install package iptables-persistent (apt-get install iptables-persistent) and save your rules in /etc/iptables/rules.v4 for ipv4 and /etc/iptables/rules.v6 for ipv6 (if any). Check out https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125833/why-isnt-the-iptables-persistent-service-saving-my-changes foe details

Comment: I have installed iptables-persistent